# How to create empty Postgresql database with Datamapper

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sinatra, datamapper, psql

I have been learning about databases and wanted to know, if is there a Datamapper method *-or another "ruby" way?-* for creating an empty database rather than using `create database "bd_name";` in `psql`, in a Sinatra project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should be doing is creating a [Rakefile](http://rake.rubyforge.org/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html) and defining a Rake task to create the database and also a task to run the migrations after you make any structural changes to your database.

With DataMapper, this is somewhat more work than with ActiveRecord (which provides it's own DB tasks).

Have a look at [the Rakefile](https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework/blob/master/padrino-gen/lib/padrino-gen/padrino-tasks/datamapper.rb) provided by the [Padrino](http://padrinorb.com/) framework for inspiration.